# Chartify: how to pass a Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bokeh, chartify

The following example should work, but it requires the `selenium` package (as I understand, under the hood `chartify` builds an interactive chart using the `bokeh` package and takes a screenshot with `selenium`)

```
import chartify

chartify.examples.plot_scatter()
```

The code above doesn't work because I can't configure a driver for Selenium, which is normally done similar to this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=(my_path + '/chromedriver)')
```

How can I pass this `driver` object to `chartify`?

Comment: https://github.com/spotify/chartify  Scroll down to "Installation".  You don't need to pass in the driver... it'll launch it, but will rely on chromedriver and chrome being in path.  (though honestly I would avoid the screenshot part if you can.  You should be able to output an HTML file?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they have hardcoded the creation and configuration of the webdriver in a Chart method [`_initialize_webdriver`](https://github.com/spotify/chartify/blob/f56743ce75b9b00781fc87a03dcee3dc095971c8/chartify/_core/chart.py#L433-L446).

If you want something different than what they do, I think monkey-patching the `Chart. _initialize_webdriver` method to override it is the only current option. It might be worth opening a issue on their GH tracker to discuss adding the ability to customize webdriver creation.

Comment: Great answer supported through an argument and the reference.